# Output voltage diagram of a 3-input OR logic gate (using diodes)

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, ground, diagram, time

Let's say we have a 3-input OR gate (using 3 diodes and a resistor) as follows:
[image: OR gate]

A hypothetical input voltages diagram is the following:
[image: voltages diagram]

I want to find the output voltage diagram (voltage Vo) that corresponds to this diagram from 0 to 6 seconds. I have drawn the following diagram:
[image: output voltage]

So:

t = 0sec to t = 3sec -> at least 1 input is non-zero (not grounded) -> output is high

t = 3sec to t = 6sec -> at least 1 input is non-zero (not grounded) -> output is high

I am not sure that this is correct. Basically, I am wondering what is the maximum and minimum output voltages.

Thanks!

Comment: assuming ideal diodes, output will follow the envelope of the three inputs.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the "envelope" in a graph?

Comment: added a picture in the answer, since I can't upload pic in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be the output assuming ideal diodes.

[image]

Comment: OK. So from t=0sec to t=3sec the result of the OR could be considered as logic "1". Is that correct? Also, can you explain me why it is "zero" from t=3sec to t=6sec ? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it would be considered as logic '1' when the inputs have logic values. For t=3sec to t=6sec U3 is zero and U1/U2 have negative value. So only D3 would be turned on and D1/D2 would be reverse biased. So only U3 will be passed to output.